# JS - why touchEvent.identifier in Chrome is always zero?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, multi-touch

i'm playing with touch events and i realized a demo that creates and moves a circle for each finger. No problem on iOS Safari, but Android Chrome returns always "0" as identifier of the touch ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/identifier ). Is it a bug, an "anti-user-tracking" privacy choice, or what else? Is there a workaround to identify the touches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to a different reading of the W3C spec than that used by Apple in iOS Safari.
Android Chrome gives an identifier of 0 for a touch when only one finger is touching the screen. When two fingers are touching, it gives them identifiers of 0 and 1 and so on. This actually conforms to the wording of the W3C spec:

[identifier of type long, readonly

An identification number for each touch point. When a touch point becomes active, it must be assigned an identifier that is distinct from any other active touch point. While the touch point remains active, all events that refer to it must assign it the same identifier.](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#dfn-touch-point)

Note it only has to be unique relative to any other active touch point, which means that it can be the same as for previous touch points that are no longer active. This is much less useful than the Apple implementation.